# Flask don't work with debug mode

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I working on my little package, and I came across with the weird `werkzeug` problem.

**Problem**:
When I tried to run my application in **debug** mode, and in order to run my application I use the command `python3 -m my_app --start`

**I got the error** `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.helpers'; '__main__' is not a package`

the files are very simple

**app.py**

```
class Application:
    """Main class"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.reader = ApplicationReader()
        self.app = Flask(self.reader.name)

    def __start_server(self):
        """Custom method, for starting flask application"""
        self.app.run(debug=True)

    def run(self):
        """Run the server"""
        return self.__start_server()


# Instance of Application class
application = Application()


def start_app():
    """Start the mock server
    """
    return application.run()
```

**__main__.py**

```
def cli(run, init, start):
    if run:
        print('Your API is running...')
    if init:
        create_init_file()
    if start:
        start_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

And seems like the bug can't be fixed, [GitHub issue](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/461)

So, maybe someone have a solution for this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I created a different file for the `start_app` function because I found that in debug mode, the import could not be realized.

**start_app.py** (next to app.py)

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
print("sys.path", sys.path) # use this to check if the last entry has the right folder
from app import start_app
start_app()
```

Now, you can run it with `python -m start_app.py` in debug mode.